# flutter I'm using gridview.count, but I can't set the height

Tags: flutter

I am using GridView.count and list.generate.

I want to set the height on the image.

I tried setting the height where needed, but there is no change

It seems my code is stupid.

It's a low level question, but I would appreciate it if you could answer it :)

```
SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      child: Container(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                        child: GridView.count(
                          mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                          crossAxisCount: 3,
                          children: List.generate(
                            snapshot.data!.length,
                            (index) => ClipRRect(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                              child: snapshot.data![index].posterPath.isEmpty
                                  ? Container()
                                  : CachedNetworkImage(
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                      imageUrl:
                                          'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/${snapshot.data![index].posterPath}',
                                    ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
```

Comment: use `childAspectRatio`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `childAspectRatio` for the size of the children of `GridView`.

It is a ratio of `width / height`.

```dart
// As tall as it is wide
childAspectRatio:1

// 3 parts width for 2 parts height (1.5 times wider than it is tall) 
childAspectRatio:3/2

// 1 part width for 2 parts height (2 times taller than it is wide) 
childAspectRatio: 1/2
```